# How does google copy link to clipboard in Docs?

Tags: clipboard, google-docs

I've read all the stuff about how it's no longer possible to copy to clipboard with a click, and the clever ways that folks like Trello are making do without this functionality... but then Google just updated Docs with the exact feature we're looking for:

[image: Image Link]

How do they do it?

Comment: Could you provide some sources or information as to why this would not be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the new execCommand api for contentEditable areas.

Documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_Compatibility

IE 10+, Chrome 43+, and Opera 29+ support these commands.